# PHP simple_html_dom find

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have several pages that I get html from. $html is the object with html from each page. I'm now getting images from the pages, some pages have one image and some pages does not have any. I want to put a value in the array if the page does not have an image, like `empty`. So I need something like `if($html->find('img')==null)` but I can't find a solution with `simple_html_dom`. Any ideas or other way to do it?

```
//using simple_html_dom

public function GetImages($dataArray) {
    $url = 'http://page/';

    foreach ($dataArray as $link) {
        $html = file_get_html($url . $link);
        if(is_object($html)){

            foreach ($html->find('img') as $image) {

                $images[] = $image->src;
            }

        }

    }
    return $images;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont compleately understand your question here however, if you pull a page you can use
`if( isset($html->find("img")) )` to check if the attribute is set.

```
// If page has any images you will add their src path to images array
if( isset($html->find("img")) )
{
    for($html->find('img') as $image) {
       if(isset($image))
       {
           $images[] = $image->src;
       } else {
           $images[] = 'Empty';
       }
    }
}
```

It would be better to use `if(isset($image->src))` if you can rewrite your question would be able to help better.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to explain some more. For each $html, that contains html from one page, I want to check if there's an img. If the $html contains an img I want to add the path to the array, and if not I want another value. The problem is I'm getting "Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context" when I use isset on $html->find.

Answer (score 0):

simple_html_dom development ceased YEARS AGO.. use the actively developed DOMDocument ( http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php ) , not simple_html_dom ...anyway

```
if(count($html->find('img'))==0){$noImages=true;};
```

(in DOMDocument, you'd use $domd->getElementsByTagName("img"), just like in javascript webdev)